# Kubernetes [RBAC]: User with access to specific Pods

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-pod

I need to give access to a set of pods within a namespace to an external support.
I've been reading about the RBAC API, [Cluster]Roles and [Cluster]Role Bindings; but I could not find anything about how to apply a role to a group of pods (based on annotations or labels).
Does anyone know if it is possible to do that?

This is the Role that I use now, and need limit it to a specific pods set:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: <ClientX>-PodMonitor
  namespace: <namespace>
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
```

If you guys need more details, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "access to pods" mean? The ability to view the logs, to exec into them, to just see the list, the ability to connect to the services running in the Pods, ...?

Comment: Initially, you only see their logs, but can also get the pods list too (only those to which have permission)

Answer (score 6):

Try below way of defining role-binding with resource name as example on [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/):

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
    namespace: default
    name: configmap-updater
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  resourceNames: ["my-configmap"]
  verbs: ["update", "get"]
```

Comment: I don't think this completely addresses @mvazquez's question, as it doesn't speak to the "based on annotations or labels" part. I would expect a full answer would include a custom controller that watches Pods and edits the `Role` to keep the `resourceNames` in sync with the annotated or labeled Pods

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments.
I had already evaluate the 'resourceName' option; It's my fault for not explain myself correctly.
'resourceName' is a great option but, for example, in my case can't use it because the role that I defining need the verb 'list'.
I will edit my question with the example to be more specific.

Comment: Right, I don't think there is a way of doing it out-of-the-box. You will have to search for or create a controller that does what @MatthewLDaniel suggested in above comment.